# Spring JPA Hibernate No ejecuta el insert

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

Disculpen, soy nuevo en Spring JPA Hibernate para crear RESTful web services. Mi situación es la siguiente: Tengo ya una base de datos a la cual no puedo agregarle columnas, entonces utilizando Spring JPA Hibernate me di cuenta que para hacer el insert de una nueva fila necesitas en la entidad poner una columna ID aunque yo ya cuento con ella.

¿Cómo puedo hacer un insert simple con JPA a mi base de datos sin modificarla?
¿Es posible utilizar esta tecnología pero orientarla a bases de datos que ya son creadas y no deben ser manipuladas?
Les dejo mi trabajo.

Les agradezco de antemano el apoyo y la atención.

```
    package com.garosoft.app.ws.io.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity(name="alumnos")
public class AlumnoEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7874981523607988040L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "idBoleta")
    private int idBoleta;//ESTE VALOR YO YA LO TENGO
    
    @Column(name = "Nombre")
    private String nombre;
    
    @Column(name = "Ap")
    private String ap;
    
    @Column(name = "Am")
    private String am;
    
    @Column(name = "FechaNacimiento")
    private String fechaNacimiento;
    
    @Column(name = "Email")
    private String email;
    
    @Column(name = "Password")
    private String password;
    
    @Column(name = "Curp")
    private String curp;
    
    @Column(name = "Telefono")
    private String telefono;
    
    @Column(name = "Direccion")
    private String direccion;
    
    @Column(name = "Escuela")
    private String escuela;
    
    @Column(name = "Carrera")
    private String carrera;
    
    
    
    public int getIdBoleta() {
        return idBoleta;
    }
    public void setIdBoleta(int IdBoleta) {
        this.idBoleta = IdBoleta;
    }
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public String getAp() {
        return ap;
    }
    public void setAp(String ap) {
        this.ap = ap;
    }
    public String getAm() {
        return am;
    }
    public void setAm(String am) {
        this.am = am;
    }
    public String getFechaNacimiento() {
        return fechaNacimiento;
    }
    public void setFechaNacimiento(String fechaNacimiento) {
        this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getCurp() {
        return curp;
    }
    public void setCurp(String curp) {
        this.curp = curp;
    }
    public String getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }
    public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }
    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }
    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }
    public String getEscuela() {
        return escuela;
    }
    public void setEscuela(String escuela) {
        this.escuela = escuela;
    }
    public String getCarrera() {
        return carrera;
    }
    public void setCarrera(String carrera) {
        this.carrera = carrera;
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: No se entiende la situación. Si no puedes agregarle columnas ¿por qué tu entidad si tiene ese atributo, y cada atributo tiene una anotación *@Column*? Hay formas de que un atributo de una entidad no se incluya en la serialización a BD, pero entonces sencillamente se perderá. ¿Cuál de estas columnas no está, y qué ha de pasar con esa información?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es porque `Hibernate` utilizan lo que se llamaría un estrategia de nombre y `Spring` la implementa con la clase `SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy`, al estrategia define como se llamaran los campos, tablas en la base de datos y en las consultas sql que genera, siguiendo tu ejemplo `idBoleta` la estrategia lo cambiaria a `id_boleta` como puedes ver no es lo mismo que tienes en tu base de datos, además que tú base no tiene un estándar claro porque el id es `idBoleta` con minúscula, pero luego las columnas de los datos son `Ap` con inicio de mayúscula, el problema no esta en hibernate esta en como se han nombrado los elementos sin un estándar y habría que saber si la base de datos es sensible a las mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Ahora bien, es posible modificar la estrategia de nombres implementando las clase `org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategy` o extendiendo la clase `SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy` después en las propiedades sobre escribes con tú clase `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=com.oersonalizado.MiEstrategia` pero viendo tus ejemplos no creo que sea el camino a seguir, mejor sobre escribir los nombres con las anotaciones.

aquí te dejo algunos link si quieres ampliar sobre el tema:

> https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-naming-strategy
>
> https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.x/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-configure-jpa-properties

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo! Como comenté, soy novato en este tema y tu comentario es muy claro. En efecto, la base de datos no tiene atributos con nombres estandarizados o con buenas prácticas y este era el problema. Como yo no me puedo meter con la BD la solución fue poner spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none, por qué incluso hasta me agregaba columnas, y en la parte de Id ponerlo de esta manera "@Id
       @Column(name="idboleta", nullable = false, unique = true)
Nótese que tuve que poner el nombre de la columna de esa forma por lo que ya habías comentado. Agradezco su atención.

Comment: Que bueno poder aclarar tus dudas, entiendo la situación en la que te encuentras, en estos casos con base de datos legadas la persistencia no siempre en caja correctamente y hay que adaptarla o optar por jdbc para tener mas control de las consultas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus consejos. Me vienen muy bien.